# Express - return certain documents with named route parameters using axios

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, express, mongoose, axios

I'm having trouble communicating between the frontend and backend for a selected GET request.

I am using a React frontend with an express/mongoose setup out in the backend.

In the frontend, I do a GET call using axios for:

```
axios.get('/api/orders/', {
    params : {
       name: this.props.user.name // user name can be Bob
    }
})
```

And in the backend I'm having a hard time understanding the *correct* method I would need to do to query the database (example below doesn't work). I found stuff with `.select` but even then I still can't get it to work:

```
router.get('/orders', function(req, res) {
    Order.find({}).select(req.params).then(function (order) { 
      res.send(req.params);
    })
});
```

I also tried doing this to see if I can even get the `params` to send properly and to no demise:

```
router.get('/orders/:name', function(req, res) {
    res.send('client sent :',req.query.name);
});
```

---

The orders document model holds objects that house an ordered array and a name (type: String) attached to the object. The Mongoose scheme for the order:

```
const orderScheme = new Schema({
    name : { type : String },
    orders : { type : Array}
});
```

In my MongoDB, I can see all the "Master Orders" send back. Each *master order* has the name of who submitted it, plus all the orders within (there can be a ton of orders).

What I'm trying to exactly do is pull up all orders that have a certain name. So if I search "TestAccount", I'll get all of bob's orders. I've included an image below:

[image]

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Client-side:**

```
axios.get('/api/orders/' + this.props.user.name)
    .then(function (response) {
        // handle success
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
```

- You need to handle the [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Description) when resolved/rejected.

**Server-side:**

```
router.get('/orders/:name', function(req, res) {
    return Order.find({name: req.params.name}).then(function(orders) { 
        // return orders when resolved
        res.send(orders);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

- You did not specify a named [route parameter](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters) in your route path.
- You also aren't accessing the `name` property by using [`req.params`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params) only.
- You should use [`Model.find()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) conditions parameter to specify which document[s] you're trying to find. [`Query.prototype.select()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) is for filtering document fields.

Comment: So I tried that way. It strangely just send backs all my order ID's (and I mean all of them..). Which many of them have a different user other then lets say "bob".

Comment: So you need to find the order made by a person named "bob" and not filter the collection fields. Answer updated.

Comment: @RobertOchinski can you post your `Orders` Mongoose schema in your question please?

Comment: I was typing   function (order) { res.send(order) } .I forgot that mongo does that plur thing. You have been great help @U-ways, thank you.